# C Program that makes a copy of a file using standard I/O and system calls

Tags: c, linux, unix

I am trying to write a C program which uses standard I/O and System calls to perform copying of contents of one file to another file.

So far, I have done this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd1, fd2;
    char buffer[1024];
    long int n1;

    if(((fd1 = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)) == -1) || ((fd2=open(argv[2],O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC, 0700)) == -1)){
        perror("file problem");
        exit(1);
    }

    while((n1=read(fd1, buffer, 1024) > 0)){
        if(write(fd2, buffer, n1) != n1){
            perror("writing problem ");
            exit(3);
        }
    }
    close(fd1);
    close(fd2);
}
```

When I run the program like this :

```
cc copyContents.c 
./a.out one.txt two.txt
```

Assuming that `one.txt` is well defined, what I want is to create a new file called `two.txt` and copy over all the contents of `one.txt`

When I look into the contents of `two.txt` after running the program, it has literally nothing in it. Just a blank file.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you done any attempt to debug this?

Comment: `while((n1=read(fd1, buffer, 1024)) > 0){`

Comment: Looks good to me.  Stop in a debugger after the read and see what's in buffer.

Comment: Note that 'standard I/O' normally refers to file streams (`FILE *`) as found in `<stdio.h>` and exemplified by `fopen()`, `fclose()`, `fread()`, `fwrite()`.  What you're using is file descriptor I/O — or some similar name.

Comment: There's no use of standard I/O in this program, just POSIX system calls.

Comment: `if(((fd1 = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)) == -1) || ((fd2=open(argv[2],O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC, 0700)) == -1)){`  Can you stuff any more into that one line?  Bad, bad, bad code.  When it fails, you can't even tell which one fails.  That kind of overstuffed code is why you couldn't figure out what was wrong - you had too much going on in those lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wrote

```
 while((n1=read(fd1, buffer, 1024) > 0)){
```

instead of

```
 while ( (n1 = read(fd1, buffer, 1024)) > 0)
```

In your code the code int the `while` condition boils down to:

```
n1 = (read(fd1, buffer, 1024) > 0)
```

So the read is done correctly, it's return value is compared to 0, the result of the comparision (0 or 1)  is assigned to `n1`.

This shows once more how important it is to format your code in a way that makes it readable.

You could have debugged this easily yourself with a debugger or by inserting one or two `printf`s in your code.

Comment: ..or just avoided the issue entirely by not writing a 'clever' compound expression that can, (and did), go wrong:(

Comment: OP says _" after running the program, it have literally nothing in it"_  ? It has at exactly 1 character , if everything is *"good"* state

Comment: @P0W that's correct, maybe there was another issue, but apart from the wrong expression in the `while` condition everything looks correct.

Comment: There's probably dozens of duplicates of this answer, it's a common mistake.

Answer (score 1):

**Input**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

void typefile (char *filename)
{
   int fd, nread;
   char buf[1024];
   fd = open (filename, O_RDONLY);
   if (fd == -1) {
   perror (filename);
   return;
}
while ((nread = read (fd, buf, sizeof (buf))) > 0)
   write (1, buf, nread);
   close (fd);
}
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  int argno;
  for (argno = 1; argno < argc; argno  )
  typefile (argv[argno]);
  exit (0);
}
```

**Output**:

```
student@ubuntu:~$gcc –o prg10.out prg10.c
student@ubuntu:~$cat > ff
hello`enter code here`
hai
student@ubuntu:~$./prg10.out ff
hello
hai
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the best solution and easily executable.

input:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
   int f1, f2;
   char buff[50];
   long int n;

 if(((f1 = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)) == -1 || ((f2=open(argv[2], O_CREAT | 
 O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC, 0700))== 1)))
    {
       perror("problem in file");
       exit(1);
    }

 while((n=read(f1, buff, 50))>0)

     if(write(f2, buff, n)!=n)
        {
           perror("problem in writing");
           exit(3);
        }

     if(n==-1)
        {
           perror("problem in reading");
           exit(2);
        }

       close(f2);
       exit(0);
 }
```

Output:

```
cc sys.c 
./a.out a.txt b.txt
cat b.txt
```

So, a.txt should have some content and this content is copied to b.txt
by "cat b.txt" you can cross-check the content(which is in "a.txt").

Answer (score 1):

Narenda checks if `n==-1` inside the loop, but, the loop test is `n>0`, so, that'll never happen.

Also, the test for a bad read should precede the attempt to write.